# Calling class function not responding as expected

Tags: javascript, class, dom, input, undefined

I have a problem with calling the variable valio, when I put text into the input and after calling it, the console returns "now registered
undefined".

I have experience with this type of calling but never happened before so could some one explain me why this doesn't work as I expected ?

```
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var comment = document.getElementById("comment");

class User{
 constructor(username,comment,email){
  this.username = username;
  this.comment = comment;
  this.email = email;
  }
  register(){
   console.log(this.username + this.comment + " is now registered");
  }
}

var valio = new User(name.value , comment.value, email.value);

       <input id="name" type="text" value=""><br>
       <input id="email" type="text" value=""><br>
       <input id="subject" type="text" value=""><br>
       <input id="comment" type="text" value=""><br>
```

Comment: does `name` stores somethink like `document.querySelector('#name')` ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect? In the title you speak of "calling class function" but in the body of the question you say you are "calling the variable." What are you calling and what do you expect to get?

Comment: Nope, only the variable above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ur variable `name` to `uname`.

```
 var uname = document.getElementById("name");
 var email = document.getElementById("email");
 var comment = document.getElementById("comment");

 class User{
  constructor(username,comment,email){
   this.username = username;
   this.comment = comment;
   this.email = email;
   }
   register(){
    console.log(this.username + this.comment + " is now registered");
   }
 }

 var valio = new User(uname.value , comment.value, email.value);

   <input id="name" type="text" value=""><br>
   <input id="email" type="text" value=""><br>
   <input id="subject" type="text" value=""><br>
   <input id="comment" type="text" value=""><br>
```

Comment: Maybe is the way i put the text into the input, becouse when i put some text into the value code it prints it out but when im typing it in the blanked space of the input of the browser it gives me this kind of error, sorry for my horrible english it not my native..

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `name` variable is conflicting with a keyword in javascript. Try renaming it to something else.

e.g.

```
var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
```

Then pass in `nameInput.value` to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You put the reference to the name input field in a variable called `name`. However, `name` is already defined as a global variable of type string:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

It can probably not be overridden.

Try changing the variable name:

```
var username = document.getElementById("name");

var valio = new User(username.value , comment.value, email.value);
```

Comment: Hello, i've created a function 
function wut(){
    console.log(uname.value);   
}
and it prints it out but when i call it in a variable it gives me undefined.